# Silverlight vs overflow = "hidden"

Tags: css, silverlight, firefox, hidden

I have a silverlight control on a page where I need to change the style of the body to overflow = "hidden", and then revert the style to overflow="auto"

Whenever the overflow style property changes, the silverlight control restarts, losing all data, and operations in progress!!!!

Happens in firefox NOT safari.  Have not tried IE yet.

Comment: Which silverlight control are you talking about?

Comment: I second that question - and you might try using the object tag (Silverlight 3) instead of the System.Web.Silverlight control from SL2.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of situations in Firefox (in fact, I've hit them) where the Silverlight plugin is effectively restarted by Firefox. My understanding is that there's very little that can be done to work around the situation.

Could you consider a different design? Maybe we can help you find a workaround that helps you maintain what you're going through, without the plugin issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Silverlight, actually the docs say this about it:

> Because of browser differences, the
>   Silverlight plug-in does not support
>   the cascading style sheets
>   (CSS)overflow property on the object
>   element or on a parent container
>   element, such as a div element.

As far as i know this *only* happens with Firefox on both Mac and Windows. Other browsers don't seem to have this problem.

There are two clunky workarounds: it only seems to happen when the overflow property is changed by a user action, such as with a `:hover` pseudoclass. When you ‘force’ the browser to hide the scrollbar the Silverlight object doesn’t restart. For example, when you set the `height` of the div to a very large height the scrollbar disappears but the object doesn’t restart.

Another workaround when you need a scrollbar is to use a custom Javascript solution. I recommend the excellent [jScrollPane jQuery plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

I've blogged about a few other Silverlight quirks (including this one) on my [blog](http://www.haykranen.nl/2011/06/07/silverlight-bugs/) btw.